# Alternative to switchTo() Selenium method

Tags: c#, selenium, modal-dialog, popupwindow

I am forced to use a RPA software and C# scripts at my current job to automate a website. Basically everything worked fine until i had to handle a webpage dialog box like the one found on [this post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13737/handle-drop-down-on-web-page-dialog-selenium-c)!

The dialog box pops up when clicking a button and it seems to have some javascript functionality behind.

I have to say that using the selenium webdriver switchTo() method allows me to handle the popup, get the htmlDocument and complete my task. However, I am forced to use this RPA software which can use its own browser or the Internet Explorer browser, therefore can't use the webdriver from the Selenium library.

Is there any other way of handling this kind of popups? Maybe another library that gives me the Selenium functionality? The most important thing is being able to read the htmlDocument in order to have access to all the webdialog elements (e.g. radio buttons, checkbox, searchbox etc.)

Comment: Anything you can do with Javascript, you can do with a standard Selenium JavascriptExecutor.  So, the possibilities are endless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately i was not able to use Selenium IJavaScriptExecutor since i have to initiate the Selenium Webdriver first in order to use the ExecuteScript method. I need to find an alternative to read any modal dialog box that appears, without using the Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: I think there are some Javascript test frameworks that could probably do it without Selenium.

Comment: What is the RPA tool in use ?

Comment: Maybe you can attach to that new window separately?